# JavaScript function does not return the values of the parameters

Tags: javascript, html

So I created a function in the script tag in the head section.
The function has 2 parameters, a and b.
So it should return the 1st parameter(a) multiplied by the 2nd parameter (b).
Then I called the function with the parameters 3 and 4 but nothing shows up.

I tried moving the js code to body section, call the function outside and inside the function.

```
function my_Function(a,b) {

    return a * b;  

}

myFunction(3,4);
```

It should appear the number 12, 3*4 = 12.

Comment: is it `my_Function` or `myFunction`?

Comment: There is a typo here. your function is `my_Function` but you called `myFunction`

Comment: Aside from the name error, note that simply calling the function won't make anything happen on the screen.

Comment: yeah it's myFunction.But that still wouldnt solve the problem.If just calling wont solve it, then how can 12 appear on the screen using the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say ' but nothing shows up' I assume you mean nothing is shown in your console. This is because you are not doing anything with the return of the function. This should solve that:

```
function my_Function(a, b) {
   return a * b;
}

console.log(my_Function(3, 4));
```

Comment: I updated my answer to show the full piece of code since you probably changed function my_Function(a, b) into the previously given example.

Comment: The main issue here is a _typo_ (missing underscore `_`), and at SO we don't answer _typo_ questions, we use the built-in "vote/flag to close as a typographical error", and the reason is simple, those question's is of no use for future users.

Comment: @LGSon However even with the typo fixed, the OP still had the same basic question: why is the returned value from the function not visible? This answer addresses that part of the question.

Comment: @Pointy Should we assume OP meant to use `console.log` or actually stored the returned value somewhere, though being empty asked the question? ... do note the edit made based on a comment OP posted (which they deleted, but said it still didn't work), where also the function were added to show it works. With that I am sure their mistake were the _typo_

Comment: @Pointy And given OP need the result on the screen, this don't cut that either.

Comment: While I agree with you the question OP asked is created poorly, meaning I needed to fix a typo and assume the behavior OP expected, I believe we are all on this site to learn. Therefore I feel no harm is done in answering this question, hoping OP will be more precise when asking a future question.

Comment: @Rik Please do note that the goal of Stack Overflow is to create a library that every programmer can use/search to find a solution to their problem. It's not a personal help desk. If someone tries to find a solution to their problem and ends up on this post, it is very likely that it does not answer their question, so IMO, it does harm. "_assume the behavior_", [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) specifically asks you not to. "_...avoid trying to answer questions which... are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem._"

Comment: @Rik As you said yourself, _" question OP asked is created poorly"_, we don't answer such questions either, for the same reason Ivar described in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the result on the body of the page.. you could append a div that contains the output of you function like :

```
function my_Function(a, b) {
   return a * b;
}

document.body.innerHTML += '<div>'+ my_Function(3,4)+ '</div>';
```